# Link to download Windows 8.1 Microsoft Native High Definition Audio Device?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio

I recently purchased a laptop with RealTek Audio Drivers. However, I'm experiencing a static noise/hiss sound whenever the sound card is enabled. I read [here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/p/19537550/20500250) that to resolve the problem, simply uninstall the RealTek device and install the Windows Native High Definition Audio Device driver, however I can't find the Windows Native Audio Driver anywhere on the Internet. Does anyone know where I can download it?

Answer (score 0):

This driver ships with Windows. As such, there is no separate download available.

After removing Realtek’s drivers, Windows should automatically use it, because it’s the “next best driver available”. A reboot may be required.